# Yammer URL scheme android

Tags: yammer

We are using a a secured browser and we can allow apps to be opened form links in the browser by white listing their URL scheme in a policy. 
I can open the Yammer app in iOS by using the yammer:// url scheme. That does not work for Android. Does anybody know the Yammer URL scheme for android. 
I found this in the manifest but I am not sure how to convert it to the scheme I need to open the Yammer app from a browser on Android.

```
<intent-filter>
<action
android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
<category
Android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
<category
Android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
<data
android:scheme="yammer"
Android:hosts="threads"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you can try as below:

```
Intent url_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
Uri.parse("yammer://threads"));
url_intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
startActivity(url_intent);
```

This worked for opening the Yammer app